# Convert to json array and pass via api

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following structure:

```
var arr = [
   {
      aaa: "aaa1",
      bbb: "bbb2"
   },
   {
      ccc: "ccc1"
   }
];

var fooBar = {
   something1: "aaa",
   something2: "bbb",
   someArray: JSON.stringify(arr)
};
```

I want to convert all of this into one variable as json and pass it to PHP server, like this:

```
var data = "request=" + JSON.stringify(fooBar);
```

But when I now try to evaluate this in PHP:

```
$output = json_decode($_POST['request']);
```

The output is null.

This is because I'm getting JSON 4 error, which means syntax error.

The problem is that someArray looks like this:

```
"[{"aaa":"aaa1","bbb":"bbb1"},{"ccc":"ccc1"}]"
```

Which is not a valid JSON. But how then can I create a valid JSON so that I can read it in PHP later?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['request'])` and see what's arriving at the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling JSON.stringify twice on some of your data - the result being this:

```
""[{\"aaa\":\"aaa1\",\"bbb\":\"bbb2\"},{\"ccc\":\"ccc1\"}]""
```

Instead just call it once at the end.

```
var arr = [
 {
   aaa: "aaa1",
   bbb: "bbb2"
 },
 {
  ccc: "ccc1"
 }
];

var fooBar = {
  something1: "aaa",
  something2: "bbb",
  someArray: arr
};

var data = "request=" + JSON.stringify(fooBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
 someArray: JSON.stringify(arr)
```

You are converting that value to a string instead of an array. What you probably mean to do is

```
var arr = [
   {
      aaa: "aaa1",
      bbb: "bbb2"
   },
   {
      ccc: "ccc1"
   }
];

var fooBar = {
   something1: "aaa",
   something2: "bbb",
   someArray: arr // Assign the array to here
};
```